# (UIApplication *) Why is there a space before the asterisk?

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *) app {
```

after UIApplication why is there a space before the asterisk?

Comment: This is just style. Some people like to use the space and some people don't. Usually those who prefer to attach the operator to the type don't use the space while people who prefer to attach the operator to the variable do use the space when typing method declarations. It's basically up to your style (or the style guides your team follows) to decide which you prefer.

Answer (score 11):

This is a [characteristic from C code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations), I'm fairly new to Objective-C so forgive me if this isn't proper objective C syntax.  It will answer the question.  The answers about it being style are mostly correct with regard to a parameter such as given in the question.  Where it is an issue is when declaring multiple variables on a single line in C or C++ (this is the part where I'm not sure if Obj-C supports this).

```
int* i;
```

and

```
int *i;
```

are equivalent; however when dealing with multiple declarations

```
int* i, j;
```

is not the same as

```
int *i, *j;
```

the * is applied to the i variable and not the int, thus you require an * on each variable you wish to make a pointer.

So the purpose of having the space after the class name is a stylistic nod to that.

Answer (score 7):

It is, as has been remarked, just style; but it is generally considered *good* style to put the space before the asterisk, rather than after (i.e. `NSString *aString;` rather than `NSString* aString;`, as the asterisk binds to the name, rather than the type; ref. Steve's answer).

The same style is then generally extended to when the type stands alone, such as in `- (NSString *) someMethod;` or `- (void) someMethodWithAnArgument:(NSString *)argumentName;`, as a matter of staying consistent.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a style preference, the space doesn't mean anything in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `int *i;` `int* i;` and `(int *) i;`
all mean different things. The first two are pointers. But the last is actually saying that "i" returns a pointer to an int. So in:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *) app {
```

That is actually saying that "app" returns a pointer